# Spark event log not able to write to s3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to write the eventlog of my spark application to s3 for consuming through the history server later , but i get below warning message in the log

> WARN S3ABlockOutputStream: Application invoked the Syncable API against stream writing to /spark_logs/eventlog_v2_local-1671627766466/events_1_local-1671627766466. This is unsupported

Below is the spark config I used:

```
config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")\
    .config("spark.eventLog.dir", 's3a://change-data-capture-cdc-test/pontus_data_load/spark_logs')\
    .config("spark.eventLog.rolling.enabled", "true")\
    .config("spark.eventLog.rolling.maxFileSize", "10m")
```

- spark version - 3.3.1
- dependant jars:

  - org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.0
  - com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.901

Only the `appstatus_local-1671627766466.inprogress` file is created, the actual log file is not created. But with my local file system its working as expected.

Comment: can i suggest in future you look in the source of the class printing the message, here `S3ABlockOutputStream` for the text of the message and see what causes it to be printed. it is straightforward to do this for most java/scala apps where the source jars are pushed out via maven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the warning means "the Application invoked the Syncable API against stream writing to /spark_logs/eventlog_v2_local-1671627766466/events_1_local-1671627766466. This is unsupported"

application code persists data to a filesystem using sync() to flush and save. clearly the spark logging is calling this. And as noted, the s3a client says "no can do".

s3 is not a filesystem. it is an object store; objects are written in single atomic operations. If you look at the S3ABlockOutputStream class *-it is all open source after all-* you can see that it may upload data, but it only completes the write in close().

therefore, it is not visible during the logging process itself. The warning is to make clear this is happening. It will appear once the log is closed.

If you want, you can set `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.downgrade.syncable.exceptions` to true and it will raise an exception instead. That really makes clear to applications like hbase that the filesystem lacks the semantics it needs.

Comment: thanks, i didn't realised the log will only appear after the spark application stopped , I can see the logs created in my completed application

Comment: it'll appear as the logs roll. does mean if the process finishes there's no log. hence the warning message and the ability to actually disable it. That's something we've turned on occasionally to see what apps were trying to sync data to s3...

Comment: In our case the same warning is raised and I don't see the logs even after the spark job completion. What might be the issue? Does s3 bucket need any kind of special permission?

Comment: well, welcome to debugging s3 integration. I'd recommend logging org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a at debug, turning on aws s3 logging and using hadoop 3.3.4 binaries with the publishing of audit info to those s3 logs.